# UITableViewCellのimageViewのサイズ

Tags: swift, xcode

storyboradにて、UITableViewにUITableViewCellを配置し、cell内のimageViewの高さを
autolayoutで可変（画面サイズによって）にしています。

この時、コードの中で、そのimageViewを正円にしようとしているのですが
imageView.frameのサイズが初回描写時とスクロールした時で異なっていて、
初回描写時だけうまく正円にならず、困っています。
tableViewをスクロールすると、再描写？して正円になり、以降はずっと正円となります。

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("sampleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as ! UIImageView
    ・・・
    // 画像を正円にする
    print(imageView.frame.size.height)  // ←初回とスクロール時で値が異なる。（初回のみ82、以降は64）
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = (imageView.frame.size.height * 0.5)
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

初回から正しく正円にするため、imageViewのサイズを正しく取れる方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ほかにもアイデアはいくつもあるでしょうが、ひとつのアイデアとして、つねに円形になる、`UIImageView`のサブクラスを使用することを考えてみます。

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

このクラス`RoundImageView`は、四隅がViewの高さの半分の半径の円弧になり、Viewのサイズを変えると、その半径も追随して変化します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実用にするには、もうすこし作りこむ必要があるかもしれませんが、Auto Layoutにる、サイズの変化に追随させるには、これだけでもできます。

Comment: 一発で解決できました！
Autolayout時の処理の流れやなぜサブクラスにすると問題ないか、など理解しなければいけませんね。
ありがとうございました